# Configure IIS as a reverse-proxy to redirect WebLogic server

Tags: iis, server, routes, weblogic

We have WebLogic server in a remote site. We want to connect this via our windows server using IIS.

We tried to do this routing using URLRewrite and Application Request Routing(ARR). But I am getting Bad Gateway Error 502.3

Is there any idea to configure IIS  as a proxy. So other users can reach web logic through IIS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkM7O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2oel.png)

Comment: could you please share the detailed error snapshot and the rule you are trying?

Comment: Added Error and rule screenshots.

Comment: make sure you have installed the certificate on both of the servers and it is under the trusted root.